# Error: requireJS config is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, amd, js-amd

My Project structure looks like this -

```
src
 |- main.js
 |- math.js
```

`math.js` is just an **AMD** module and I am requiring it in `main.js`

I have installed `require.js` using npm and requiring it in `main.js`

```
//main.js

var rjs = require('requirejs');

rjs.config({
  //Pass the top-level main.js/index.js require
  //function to requirejs so that node modules
  //are loaded relative to the top-level JS file.
  nodeRequire: require,
  
});

rjs(["./math.js"], function(math) {
  console.log(math.add(2, 3));
});
```

```
//math.js

define("math", function() {
  function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  function subtract(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }
  function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  }
  function divide(a, b) {
    return a / b;
  }
  
  return { add, subtract, multiply, divide };
});
```

While running `r.js ./src/main.js`, I am getting the below error.

```
rjs.config is not a function
    at /Users/dheerajmahra/Desktop/learning/different-module-formats/src/main.js:3:5
    at /Users/dheerajmahra/Desktop/learning/different-module-formats/src/main.js:14:2
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:96:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:38)
    ....
```

Comment: You are confusing the two approaches here from this page: https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html, just do `npm i requirejs` and don't run through `r.js`

Comment: If you are using the r.js file directly, replace require('requirejs') with require('./path/to/r.js').

Comment: @Joel Thanks! I was mixing the two things together. It worked now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based of reading the [requirejs-docs](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html), it seems that you are conflating the two approaches here, one being through the node-package, the other one being through the `r.js` standalone file.

It seems like you either haven't done `npm i requirejs` or, you are not running through the node process.

If you are using the `r.js` file directly, replace `require('requirejs')` with `require('./path/to/r.js')`.